Troubles when connecting with RDS MySQL instance from MySQL workbench
I created this MySQL RDS instance:

With the Connectivity & security section looking like this:

The following inbound rules:

And this routes config:

When I test the connection from MySQL workbench:

It allways throws me this error window:

I've troubleshooting this for a hours and can't get it fixed. If you need any other information please ask for it, I'm pretty new to AWS in general. THX

Steps to resolve the issue:

Ensure public access is enabled for your RDS instance.

Make sure that the RDS instance is accessible from external networks by enabling "Publicly accessible" when creating or modifying the instance.


Update inbound rules in the VPC security group:

Go to the Security Groups section in your AWS VPC settings.
Modify the inbound rules to allow access from your local IP address on port 3306 (default MySQL port).
Ensure that the security group associated with the RDS instance allows inbound connections from your IP.

Example Configuration:

Type: MySQL/Aurora
Protocol: TCP
Port: 3306
Source: Your IP address (or 0.0.0.0/0 for public access).

After updating the inbound rules, the connection issue should be resolved.


Screenshots for reference:

Inbound rules before update:


Inbound rules after update:



